# How to deal with phantomJS coredump?

Tags: phantomjs

Earlier, phantomJS core-dumped during a URL request
and related processing.  (My shell does not capture core,
so I can't tell you what happened.)

I presume this is a bug in phantomJS.  But more generally,
what is the recommended best practice for handling fatal
behavior in phantomJS?  Does the process just return non-zero
if it fails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJs has lots of little problems, crashing may be because it's out of memory (even if you have free pagefile space)  or because you use it too many times without restarting, or if you try loading in resources it doesn't process properly (like .otf webfonts) or if there's an error in your script, or if you try rendering an image that's too big, or....     well, you get the picture.

The best way to troubleshoot this is to use console.write() statements in your script (everywhere, including in all the WebPage callbacks) and use this to narrow down where the crash is occurring.

The troubleshooting technique is rather crude, but I used this to great effect in my own usages of PhantomJs.